# Call a function in angular js with its parameter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am calling a function from below:-

```
<a href="#" ng-click="editExpense('{{expense.Expense.id}}')">Edit</a>
```

In inspect element i am getting the id is '12'. but in function below:-

```
 $scope.editExpense = function(id){
     alert(id);
 }
```

Id is showing "expense.Expense.id".Then How can i pass the parameter. Is there any other way to call a function with angular js variables value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to use curly brackets in a ngDirective.

```
<a href="#" ng-click="editExpense(expense.Expense.id)">Edit</a>
```

Comment: Thanx, sir. You are genius.... you saved my times. I was trying it for two hours.

Comment: I had the same problem too when I started with angular :)